# Listview Changing Colour Of Duplicate Sub Items

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a listview that is populated, how would I go about changing the font colour if the sub item already exists in that column?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work correctly

```
Sub dupeInterpreters(lvw As ListView, iSubItemIndex As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dupeI As Integer

    dupeI = 0

    For i = 1 To LVIV.ListItems.Count

        If LVIV.ListItems(i).SubItems(iSubItemIndex) = LVIV.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).Text Then 'you could also use the LIKE operator
            'LVIV.ListItems(i).Selected = True
            LVIV.ListItems(i).Bold = True
            LVIV.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).ForeColor = &HC000&
            dupeI = dupeI + 1
            'Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

No error, but it highlights every item in the listview, rather than just the duplicate values

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/))? Please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried. This is not a free coding service. Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: Apologies, I have added my code

Comment: *"but it doesn't work correctly"* doesn't help us to understand what's going wrong with your code. You need to [edit] and explain either what errors you got or what your code did instead of what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following macro, which formats all duplicates...

```
Sub dupeInterpreters(LVIV As ListView, iSubItemIndex As Integer)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim bDuplicate As Boolean

    bDuplicate = False
    For i = 1 To LVIV.ListItems.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To LVIV.ListItems.Count
            If LVIV.ListItems(j).SubItems(iSubItemIndex) = LVIV.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).Text Then
                'LVIV.ListItems(i).Selected = True
                LVIV.ListItems(j).Bold = True
                LVIV.ListItems(j).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).ForeColor = &HC000&
                bDuplicate = True
            End If
        Next j
        If bDuplicate Then
            With LVIV.ListItems(i)
                .Bold = True
                .ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).ForeColor = &HC000&
            End With
            bDuplicate = False
        End If
    Next

    Me.Repaint

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This kind of works, and thanks so much - but this is only highlighting 2 out of 3 duplicates. e.g. It shows *John* three times, but only 2 of them are highlighted - what would this be resulting to?

Comment: The code only compares a row with the one immediately before it, no other row.  Does this explain your results?  If so, do you want the comparison to occur no matter which row the duplicate occurs?

Comment: Ahh, that explains it - I was trying to compare to any value in the column. but really thanks for trying, it is very much appreciated

Comment: You're very welcome.  Also, see my alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.  This one uses the Dictionary object to avoid excessive looping, and should be more efficient...

```
Sub dupeInterpreters(LVIV As ListView, iSubItemIndex As Integer)

    Dim dicListSubItemCount As Object
    Dim strListSubItem As String
    Dim listItemIndex As Long

    Set dicListSubItemCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dicListSubItemCount.comparemode = 1 'case-insensitive comparison

    With LVIV
        For listItemIndex = 1 To .ListItems.Count
            strListSubItem = .ListItems(listItemIndex).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).Text
            dicListSubItemCount(strListSubItem) = dicListSubItemCount(strListSubItem) + 1
        Next listItemIndex
        For listItemIndex = 1 To .ListItems.Count
            strListSubItem = .ListItems(listItemIndex).ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).Text
            If dicListSubItemCount(strListSubItem) > 1 Then
                With .ListItems(listItemIndex)
                    .Bold = True
                    .ListSubItems(iSubItemIndex).ForeColor = &HC000&
                End With
            End If
        Next listItemIndex
    End With

    Me.Repaint

    Set dicListSubItemCount = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for an alternative answer!